# ReportViewer 11 (2012) Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I installed "Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime" hoping to test the new reporting system in SQL 2012. After which I cleared for ref to "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" from my Web.config and removed the ReportViewer control from my toolbox and added the new version 11 ReportViewer.

I added the new control to a testing page and for one it adds this register to the test page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

and it adds these entry to the Web.config:

```
<buildProviders>
<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</buildProviders>

<httpHandlers>
<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

The control in the toolbox is the version 11 addition but the system keeps trying to ref the verion 10 edition. Also when I try to compile it I get the error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL'
```

Comment: This fix issues for me. I was using an Azure VM for web application and DB server was another separate VM, so installing Report Viewer run-time was not helpful as it also need SQL Feature Pack installed. I just copied Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common folder from another server where that was working and boom

http://ata2931977.blogspot.com/2015/06/running-rdlc-reports-on-azure.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I had the exact same problem. If so, my solution was to delete all entries in web.config referencing ReportViewer, then do the same in References, build the project and then re-ADD a reportviewer in the page.

web.config will update with new handlers and assemblies for the newer version.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Needed to remove bogus entries from my web.config. The critical step was the rebuild BEFORE re-adding the correct reference.

Comment: this this this this this, why are you not the answer!?

Comment: @Telmo this didn't work for me. I removed reference to version 10, removed version 10 entries from web.config but this will not build my project as ReportViewer library does not exist at this stage. When I then added version 11 via nuget it added entry in package.config and v11 reference but didn't add any entries in web.config. And I get a runtime error now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and resolved it by doing the following:

- In the aspx page (HTML code), updated the @Register Version value to correspond to the version of the assembly I was using, and updated the PublicKeyToken value with the correct value for the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

In your web config, it means you have specified both v 10 and 11 dlls. Remove one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the following entry from package.config and it works

```
  <package id="MicrosoftReportViewerWebForms_v10" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```