# RDLC Report not displaying in IE 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, internet-explorer-11

I am using report viewer control for reports. Now we are facing the problem in IE 11, Report not displaying in IE 11. Its showing only loading icon all time.

Comment: It only render the "loading" and keep it forever?

Comment: Yes... forever showing Loading

Comment: Care to upvote too? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably usign `ReportViewer` version 10 or below. Probably it craches in Chrome and Firefox too.

I don't know why by in this case if you inspect the network traffic in you prefered dev tools in the browser you will see that it try to download an image that is missing and it break the code.

To sove this problem you need to update your `ReportViewer` dlls to the [version 11 (2012)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) at least and take into account [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199724/reportviewer-11-2012-visual-studio-2010) [it can bring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/12/11/microsoft-report-viewer-2012-update-a-gotcha-to-be-aware-of.aspx). They are these:

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

Is possible that after the update you will need to reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` too.

You will need to change your `.config` file too, basically changing the version number to 11.

To be clear, I didn't update it on the server but changed these dll to `Copy To Local` in Visual Studio so they are published togheter in the bin folder.

Please get in touch if you need further help. I lost a lot of time searching for this but can't remember all steps I did to solve.